# How to write subqueries in ksql streams

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have two streams, and I can only select data from stream 1 if the country is in another stream.

SELECT * FROM `stream1` P
where
P.COUNTRYCODE = (SELECT COUNTRYCODE FROM `stream2` D where D.countrycode = P.countrycode LIMIT 1) ;